Read JSON format string column in SQL table and parse it recursively for all the rows in table ignoring nulls
I have a table with columns source_id, source_file, source_name, source_file_path, config where the column config contains the JSON text with values like this. I need to parse the config column to rows and also get values of other columns.
insert into [config].[source_test] 
values 
    ('1', 'abc1_file', 'abc1', '/etc/abc/conf/abc1_file.json', '{"name": {"min_max_nodes": "2:8", "file_type":"incremental"} ,   "source_header_flag": "n",   "destination_header_flag": "n"}'),
    ('2', 'abc2_file', 'abc2', '/etc/abc/conf/abc2_file.json', '{"name": {"min_max_nodes": "2:8", "file_type":"incremental"} ,   "source_header_flag": "n",   "destination_header_flag": "n"}'),
    ('3', 'abc3_file', 'abc3', '/etc/abc/conf/abc3_file.json', '{"name": {"min_max_nodes": "4", "file_type":"full"} , "path": "/etc/abc3/filename", "source_header_flag": "y",   "destination_header_flag": "y"}'),
    ('4', 'abc4_file', 'abc4', '/etc/abc/conf/abc4_file.json', 'NULL'),
    ('5', 'abc5_file', 'abc5', '/etc/abc/conf/abc5_file.json', '{"name": {"min_max_nodes": "8", "file_type":"full"}, "path": "/etc/abc5/filename", "source_header_flag": "y",      "destination_header_flag": "y"}'),
    ('6', 'abc6_file', 'abc6', '/etc/abc/conf/abc6_file.json', 'NULL')


How to get the output as above into rows and columns?  I have tried below method posted on this site, but the output works if I pass the hardcoded value of 1 config column to the JSON variable. But I am looking for output as above mentioned in the table by reading table data for all rows.

declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'
     {"name": 
         {
             "min_max_nodes": "2:8",
             "file_type":"incremental"
         },     
         "source_header_flag": "y",
         "destination_header_flag": "y"
     }'

select 
    oj.source_header_flag, oj.destination_header_flag,
    bo.min_max_nodes, bo.file_type
from 
    openjson(@json) 
    with 
        (source_header_flag        nvarchar(4000), 
         destination_header_flag   nvarchar(4000),
         name                      nvarchar(max) as json) oj
cross apply
    openjson(oj.name) 
    with (min_max_nodes nvarchar(4000), 
          file_type     nvarchar(max) as json) bo;


why not just do: select * from yourtable CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(config) ... and then just continue on the code you posted without the declare and variable thingy

I would do this in the app. SQL is better used to save and retrieve data.

@siggemannen, tried the suggestion by removing declare and variable section: select oj.source_header_flag, oj.destination_header_flag,
bo.min_max_nodes,
bo.file_type
from config.source_test
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(config)  with (source_header_flag        nvarchar(4000),
destination_header_flag    nvarchar(4000),
name                    nvarchar(max) as json) oj
CROSS APPLY
openjson(oj.name) with (min_max_nodes    nvarchar(4000),
file_type        nvarchar(max) as json) bo;

Getting error as " Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 60
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'N' is found at position 0"

'NULL' is not really json. You can do: CROSS apply (NULLIF(config, 'NULL'))...  so it's converted to proper NULL and not just NULL string. Even better to fix your source table so it doesn't contain 'NULL' strings, but rather NULL value

The varchar value null is valid json, NULL isn't.

you specified NULL - as a string "NULL" not a null as DBNull.Value.  it will work if you replace 'NULL' with  NULL  (as a value not as string)

replace 'NULL' with null (without quotes). or add where config <> 'NULL'. select
oj.source_header_flag,
oj.destination_header_flag,
bo.min_max_nodes, bo.file_type
from @source_test
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(config) with (
source_header_flag nvarchar(200),
destination_header_flag nvarchar(200),
name nvarchar(max) as json) oj
CROSS APPLY openjson(oj.name) with (
min_max_nodes nvarchar(4000),
file_type nvarchar(20)) bo

There's no nesting involved here. A SQL query can't return arbitrary columns. You need to specify all the columns in the WITH clause along with the path to values, eg $.name.file_type

Thanks everyone for the valuable comments. I have tried the suggestions mentioned here and got the output I was looking for.

select oj.source_header_flag, oj.destination_header_flag, bo.min_max_nodes, bo.file_type
from config.source_test a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(NULLIF(config, 'NULL')) with (
source_header_flag nvarchar(4000), destination_header_flag nvarchar(4000), name nvarchar(max) as json) oj
CROSS APPLY openjson(oj.name) with (
min_max_nodes nvarchar(4000), file_type nvarchar(max) as json) bo;

There's no nesting involved. The config columns contains a single JSON object. A SQL query can't return an arbitrary number of rows though. Relational tables aren't spreadsheets. The WITH clause must specify all the possible columns and their types:
The following example :
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'
 {"name": 
     {
         "min_max_nodes": "2:8",
         "file_type":"incremental"
     },     
     "path": "/etc/abc5/filename",
     "source_header_flag": "y",
     "destination_header_flag": "y"
 }'

select *
from 
    openjson(@json) 
    with 
    (min_max_nodes nvarchar(4000) '$.name.min_max_nodes', 
     file_type nvarchar(4000) '$.name.file_type', 
     path nvarchar(4000) '$.path',
     source_header_flag nvarchar(4) '$.source_header_flag', 
     destination_header_flag   nvarchar(4) '$.destination_header_flag'
) oj

Produces
min_max_nodes   file_type   path                source_header_flag  destination_header_flag
2:8             incremental /etc/abc5/filename  y                   y

